# Mutating multiple columns dynamically while conditioning on specific rows

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I know there are several similar questions around here, but none of them seems to address the precise issue I'm having.

```
set.seed(4)
df = data.frame(
  Key = c("A", "B", "A", "D", "A"),
  Val1 = rnorm(5),
  Val2 = runif(5),
  Val3 = 1:5
)
```

I want to zeroise values of the value columns for the rows where Key == "A"
The column names are referenced through a `grep`:

```
cols = grep("Val", names(df), value = TRUE)
```

Normally to achieve what I want in this case I would use `data.table` like this:

```
library(data.table)
df = as.data.table(df)
df[Key == "A", (cols) := 0]
```

And the desired output is like this:

```
  Key      Val1       Val2 Val3
1   A  0.000000 0.00000000    0
2   B -1.383814 0.55925762    2
3   A  0.000000 0.00000000    0
4   D  1.437151 0.05632773    4
5   A  0.000000 0.00000000    0
```

However this time I need to use `dplyr` as I am working on a team project where everyone uses it. The data I just provided is illustrative and my real data is >5m rows with 16 value columns to be updated. The only solution I could come up with is using `mutate_at` like this:

```
df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(cols), .funs = function(x) ifelse(df$Key == "A", 0, x))
```

However, this seems to be *extremely* slow on my real data. I was hoping to find a solution which is more elegant and, more importantly, faster.

I have tried many combinations using `map`, unquoting using `!!`, using `get` and `:=` (which annoyingly can get masked by the `:=` in data.table) etc, but I think my understanding of how these work is simply not deep enough to construct a valid solution.

Comment: how long does this take? df[df$Key=="A",cols]<-0. I can see that it is slow because you are calling ifelse and looping over the columns and rows.

Comment: StupidWolf, This is actually very fast with my data, while being very compact and elegant. Thanks. Feel free to add it as an answer if you wish.

Comment: Ok I can show you another solution to get around it..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With this dplyr command,

```
df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(cols), .funs = function(x) ifelse(df$Key == "A", 0, x))
```

You are actually evaluating the statement df$Key == "A", n times, where n=the number of columns you have.

One work around is to pre-define the rows you want to change:

```
idx = which(DF$Key=="A")
DF %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(cols), .funs = function(x){x[idx]=0;x})
```

A cleaner and better way, correctly pointed out by @IceCreamToucan (see comments below), is to use the function replace, while passing it the extra parameters:

```
DF %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(cols), replace, DF$Key == 'A', 0)
```

We can put all these approaches to test, and I think dplyr and data.table are comparable.

```
#simulate data
set.seed(100)
Key = sample(LETTERS[1:3],1000000,replace=TRUE)
DF = as.data.frame(data.frame(Key,matrix(runif(1000000*10),nrow=1000000,ncol=10)))
DT = as.data.table(DF)

cols = grep("[35789]", names(DF), value = TRUE)

#long method
system.time(DF %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(cols), .funs = function(x) ifelse(DF$Key == "A", 0, x)))
user  system elapsed 
  0.121   0.035   0.156 

#old base R way
system.time(DF[idx,cols] <- 0)
   user  system elapsed 
  0.085   0.021   0.106 

#dplyr
# define function
func = function(){
       idx = which(DF$Key=="A")
       DF %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(cols), .funs = function(x){x[idx]=0;x})
}
system.time(func())
user  system elapsed 
  0.020   0.006   0.026

#data.table
system.time(DT[Key=="A", (cols) := 0])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.012   0.001   0.013 
#replace with dplyr
system.time(DF %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(cols), replace, DF$Key == 'A', 0))
user  system elapsed 
  0.007   0.001   0.008
```

Comment: extra arguments to mutate are evaluated once and passed as a parameter to the function provided (similar to e.g. lapply), so you can do this without an explicitly creating the temp variable idx  as `df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains('Val')), replace, df$Key == 'A', 0)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @IceCreamToucan, I did not know it. Yup, the replace function is even better, and less clumsy than me. I will include it in the answer if you don't mind? (credit to you of course).

Comment: After testing on my machine, it seems the `replace` method is a bit slower than your original `idx` method.

Comment: Also I think `dplyr::if_else()` is faster than base `ifelse()`.